# why does my pandapower coding always error on every bus and won't work?

Tags: pandapower

I have a task pandapower, to do this (see picture) but there is always an error on the part of the bus, and the transformer does not work for the 69kv generator and the local generator is 13.8kv, can anyone give me a solution?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. "Can anyone give me a solution?" is not an adequate question, and "there is always an error / X does not work" is not an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: Probably you did something wrong – but it's really hard to guess what you did and what could go wrong without your code....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.